# How to pass SSL certs in Cypress POST request

Tags: ssl-certificate, cypress

To get successful response, passing same options object with NPM request module but `cy.request(options)` throws `403 error`.

```
var options = { 
    method: 'POST',
    agentOptions: {
        key: cy.readFile('cypress/support/transport.key'),
        cert: cy.readFile('cypress/support/transport.pem')
    }
};
```

Please guide how to pass SSL certificates in Cypress request.